# Что означает n-канальный кеш L1/L2..?

Tags: c, многопоточность, процессор

Что означает n-канальный кеш  L1/L2.. ? Иными словами, что такое каналы кеша, и на что они влияют. Так же интересно, сколько параллельных обращений к кешу L1 может делать одно ядро. То-есть, если я хочу сделать атомарное чтение из 2 строк кеша, будут ли они делаться параллельно, и сколько таких чтений можно сделать параллельно. Так же интересно сколько строк в современных L1 кешах

Comment: Все эти L кеши различаются скоростью. 1 кеш обычно самый маленький, а 3 - самый большой. Но при этом 1 самый быстрый, а 3 - самый медленный.

Comment: n-канальный -- это n-way cache? (я не уверен, что понимаю вашу терминологию. Постарайтесь использовать общепринятую (на английском))

Comment: Да, n-канальный -- это n-way cache (по крайней мере в терминологии русской вики) [Там  же](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) и описано, что вас интересует

Comment: Вот (imho) [неплохой ресурс](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/fully-associative-cache) с вполне доступными описаниями на данную тему